# Does $\{ x^* \circ \psi_t:x^*\in ext(E^*), t\in K \}\subset ext(X^*)$ hold?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Notations:** Let $K$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $E$ be a real normed linear space.
Recall that $C_0(K,E)$ is the set of $E$-valued continuous functions $f$ on $K$ such that $f$ vanishes at infinity.

For any $t\in K,$ let $\psi_t$ be an evaluation functional on $C_0(K,E).$

If $X^*$ is a dual space of $X,$ then denote $ext(X^*)$ to be the set of extreme points of the unit ball of $X^*.$

---

The following corollary is quoted in the book ['Isometries on Banach Spaces: Function Spaces' by Fleming and Jamison](https://www.crcpress.com/Isometries-on-Banach-Spaces-function-spaces/Fleming-Jamison/p/book/9781584880400), Chapter $2,$ page $33,$

> Corollary $2.3.6.$ If $X$ is a subspace of $C_0(K,E),$ then 
>   $$ext(X^*) \subset \{ x^* \circ \psi_t:x^*\in ext(E^*), t\in K \}.$$

I would like to ask whether the reverse inclusion holds, that is, 
does 
$$\{ x^* \circ \psi_t:x^*\in ext(E^*), t\in K \}\subset ext(X^*)$$
hold? 
If yes, can provide a proof or its reference? 
Otherwise, can I have counterexample?

Comment: This should depend on the subspace $X\subseteq C_0(K,E)$!

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: I see. So the reverse inclusion is false in general. May I know what conditions on the subspace $X$ would turn the reverse inclusion true? For example, reflexive? Strictly convex?

Comment: What happens in the easier case when $E=\mathbb C$?  Then you are comparing $ext(X^*)$ for $X\subseteq C_0(K)$ with the collection of all evaluation functions on $K$.

Comment: @Matthew Daws perhaps you can write your comment as an answer so that I can give a closure to my question?